# low level multi part upload performance issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-s3, multipart

I am using low level multi part upload API and it takes 50 min to upload 240 GB file. I want to know if this is average time or it can be improved. I don't see option to use multiple threads in low level API like TransactionManager. I also tried to use high level API using TransactionManager but unable to get it working. Its giving this error. Its removing one slash after hdfs: somehow. Also providing code i am using for high level API. I need to copy file from hdfs to s3.

```
 com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to calculate MD5 hash: hdfs:/ip-**-***-*-**.ec2.internal:8020/user/***@awsmac.**.com/s3speedTest.txt (No such file or directory)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1705)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInOneChunk(UploadCallable.java:131)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.call(UploadCallable.java:123)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:143)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: hdfs:/ip-**-***-*-**.ec2.internal:8020/user/***@awsmac.**.com/s3speedTest.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at com.amazonaws.util.Md5Utils.computeMD5Hash(Md5Utils.java:97)
    at com.amazonaws.util.Md5Utils.md5AsBase64(Md5Utils.java:104)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1701)
```

This is the code:

```
def multiPartUploadHighLevelNew(spark:SparkSession,bucketName:String,keyName:String,hdfsFilePath:String,kmsKey:String):Unit={
    try {
      val startTime = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHH:mm:ss").print(DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC))
      println("start time="+startTime)
      import java.util.concurrent.Executors
      val maxUploadThreads = 5
      val s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard.withRegion(Regions.getCurrentRegion.getName)
        .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance()).build
    
      val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
      val hdfsTopLevelPath=fs.getWorkingDirectory()+"/"+hdfsFilePath
      println(hdfsTopLevelPath)
      val file=new File(hdfsTopLevelPath)
      val request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, file)
        .withSSEAwsKeyManagementParams(new SSEAwsKeyManagementParams(kmsKey))
        .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.BucketOwnerFullControl)
        val tm= TransferManagerBuilder.standard.withS3Client(s3Client).build

      // TransferManager processes all transfers asynchronously,
      // so this call returns immediately.
      val upload = tm.upload(request)
      System.out.println("Object upload started")

      // Optionally, wait for the upload to finish before continuing.
      upload.waitForCompletion
      System.out.println("Object upload complete")
      val endTime = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHH:mm:ss").print(DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC))
      println("start time="+endTime)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Is it the exception you show here, or the amount of time to upload the file? If the latter, how long did you _expect_ it to take, and what is that based on?

Comment: Also, please do a better job of formatting. It looks like you know how to use code formatting, so please format code as code and text as text.

Comment: I tried with low level multipart upload and it took 50 min to upload 240 GB file but i tried the same with aws s3 cp command and it takes does copy 3 times faster. I did not see option to use multiple threads in low level API. Then, i tried to use high level upload API to use TransactionManager which has option to provide multiple threads to make upload faster. But, seeing this exception in using high level API code. The issue here is that its removing one slash from HDFS URL (hdfs:/ instead of hdfs://) and then it fails with error that path is not valid.